# How to pipe multiple results into a command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, aws, bash-expansion, bash-array

I have a piece of code which works, something like this (note this is inside CloudFormation Template for AWS auto deployment):

```
EFS_SERVER_IPS_ARRAY=( $(aws efs describe-mount-targets --file-system-id ${SharedFileSystem} | jq '.MountTargets[].IpAddress' -r) )
echo "IPs in EFS_SERVER_IPS_ARRAY:"
for element in "${EFS_SERVER_IPS_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
    echo "$element $MOUNT_SOURCE" >> /etc/hosts
done
```

This works but looks ugly. I want to avoid the array variable and the `for` loop (basically I don't care about the first echo command).

Can I somehow use the output ($element, which is 1 or more, currently 2 lines of IPs) and funnel it into two executions of something like:

```
long AWS command >> echo $element $MOUNT_SOURCE  >> /etc/hosts
```

with echo executing as many times as there are variables in the array, in current implementation? How would I rewrite this?

The output of the AWS command is like this:

```
10.10.10.10
10.22.22.22
```

Then, the added lines in `/etc/hosts` look like:

```
10.10.10.10  unique-id.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
10.22.22.22  unique-id.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: @Jesse_b I edited, added sample output of the aws command. efs host needs two columns: the IP outputted, and the hostname in $MOUNT_SOURCE variable defined outside the snipped I added)

Comment: Yes but is this really adding the IP address to your `/etc/hosts`?  It seems more likely it is just adding the literal numbers `0` and `1` to it.

Comment: @Jesse_b yes it works, already tested on AWS deployment. Why do you think it should output just 0 and 1?

Comment: @Jesse_b, Are you suggesting that potentially, if there'd be only one IP returned (single availability zone), it wont be an array anymore, and break the code? Currently as you see in the snippet, I have @ sign, I have array assignment =(..), so I am not sure if I get your point?

Comment: No I'm saying that when an array is called with the `${!name[@]}` syntax it will expand to a list of the **indices** (0 1 2 3, etc) and **not** the *elements* (ip1 ip2 ip3, etc).

Comment: ohh I see, the `!` is an escape character inside cloud formation templates, it disappears when it is actually run by AWS, as referenced here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html quote: `To write a dollar sign and curly braces (${}) literally, add an exclamation point (!) after the open curly brace, such as ${!Literal}. AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as ${Literal}.` So, maybe I should just remove that stuff to make it less confusing? :)

Comment: @Jesse_b I edited, it should be clear now - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the effort with your answer @Jesse_b, I didnt think jq could possibly be the solution :)

Comment: You probably want to quote `"${SharedFileSystem}"`.

Comment: @wchargin why quote it?

Comment: @Carmageddon: Without quoting, `${SharedFileSystem}` is subject to expansion (of various forms) and word splitting. As a general rule of thumb for shell, quote everything unless you have a specific reason not to _and_ you understand well the potential inputs and how those behave under expansion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
aws efs describe-mount-targets --file-system-id ${SharedFileSystem} \
    | jq --arg mntsrc "$MOUNT_SOURCE" '.MountTargets[].IpAddress | . + $mntsrc' -r >> /etc/hosts
```

or, if you prefer,

```
aws efs describe-mount-targets --file-system-id ${SharedFileSystem} \
    | jq '.MountTargets[].IpAddress' -r | sed -e "s~\$~$MOUNT_SOURCE~" >> /etc/hosts
```

All that's happening is adding some extra fixed text to the end of each line, which can happen either in `jq` (top) or in various ways outside (bottom). There's not really any array context here or anything being repeated, so you don't need a loop.

Comment: Damn hot! Thanks Michael!! I am a happy puppy now, the first one is great. I didnt know about the --args on jq, neat :)